# How to make code generation depending on template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

can I prevent the generation of a function of a templated class if the template arguments does not meet a criteria (certain value or type)?
Can this be achieved by using c++ code and no preprocessor directives?

This kind of function should neither be available in the header nor in the body.
This case may seem a little artificial but i did not find a solution yet.

Example class (simplified - no constructor etc.):

**MyClass.h**

```cpp
template<int Dimension, typename TPixelType = float>
    class MyClass
{
    void DoSomething();
    void DoAnotherThing(); // this function should only be available if Dimension > 2
}
```

**MyClass.cxx**

```cpp
template< int Dimension, typename TPixelType> void MyClass::DoSomething()
{...}

// pseudocode: if Dimension <= 2 do not compile next function
template< int Dimension, typename TPixelType> void MyClass::DoAnotherThing() 
{
    MethodNotToBeCompiled(); // The function I don't want to be executed
}
```

**TestMyClass.cxx**

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto myclass0 = MyClass<2>();
    myclass0.DoSomething(); // OK
    myclass0.DoAnotherThing(); // (wanted) error - function not available

    auto myclass1 = MyClass<3>();
    myclass1.DoSomething(); // OK
    myclass1.DoAnotherThing(); // OK
}
```

**Is this possible in C++XX? Or is there another approach than preprocessor directives?**

Comment: not the question but relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file

Comment: out of curisity: how would you use the preprocessor? I have no idea how that could be done with the preprocessor

Comment: You can specialize templates, so this is conceptually trivial. How to write "good" code for large template classes with specializations is a different matter (inheritance can help). But maybe SFINAE is also sufficient in your case.

Comment: `static_assert(2 < Dimension)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General suggestion: if you have a template class, implement all in the header and avoid cpp files. All become a lot simpler.

> can I prevent the generation of a function of a templated class if the template arguments does not meet a criteria (certain value or type)? Can this be achieved by using c++ code and no preprocessor directives?

Yes and yes: search for SFINAE.

In your case (C++11 and newer)

```
template <int Dimension, typename TPixelType = float>
class MyClass
 {
   public:
      void DoSomething ()
       { }

      template <int D = Dimension,
                typename std::enable_if<(D > 2), bool>::type = true>
      void DoAnotherThing()
       { }
 };
```

Now the `DoAnotherThing()` method is implemented only when `D > 2` where `D`, by default is equal to `Dimension`.

Isn't a perfect solution because can be "hijacked" explicating the value of `D`

```
auto myclass0 = MyClass<2>();
myclass0.DoAnotherThing<5>(); // compile because D is 5
```

but you can prevent this problem adding the test that `D` is equal to `Dimension`

```
  template <int D = Dimension, // ..VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
            typename std::enable_if<(D == Dimension)
                                 && (D > 2), bool>::type = true>
  void DoAnotherThing()
   { }
```

so

```
auto myclass0 = MyClass<2>();
myclass0.DoAnotherThing<5>(); // doesn't compile anymore because 5 != 2
```

Comment: This can be combined with ```if constexpr(){}``` to prevent the function call throwing compile time errors.

Answer (score 7):

```
template <int Dimension, typename TPixelType> void MyClass::DoSomething()  {/*...*/}

// if Dimension <= 2 do not compile next function
template <int Dimension, typename TPixelType>
void MyClass::DoAnotherThing() 
{
    static_assert(Dimension > 2, "function not available!" );
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How do I handle the code after the ```static_assert()```? It seems that static_assert affects the whole compilation process. I just want a sinlge function not compiling.

Comment: what do you mean? when you using this function with invalid parameter (`<=2`) the compilator doesn't allow you to do it and gives you an error `function not available!`.
The code after `static_assert()` should be like normal code, there is no difference.
In example after `static_assert(...);` you can put: `int i = Dimension * 3;`

Comment: Does the assert prevent the compiling of this method or just the execution? I trying to figure out at what point the ```static_assert``` unfolds its functionality.

Comment: @KabCode `static_assert` gives you the compile-time error, so it prevents the compiling.

Answer (score 6):

In C++2a, you might use `requires` to "discard" method:

```
template<int Dimension, typename TPixelType = float>
class MyClass
{
    void DoSomething();
    void DoAnotherThing() requires (Dimension > 2);
};
```

Comment: How far is the implentation of C++2a? Can it be already used (with Visual compiler)?

Comment: You might look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=vs-2019. So currently not yet supported in visual (gcc supports `requires`).

Comment: This would be my prefered answer if i could use ```requires```.

Comment: @Jarod42 is too ahead of his/her time :-) cool solution nonetheless, [happy to have tried it out](https://godbolt.org/z/s8BZ3N)!